# Concept - Firing events on a resource load

Tags: javascript

Is there any library that does this?

Is there a pure code way to do it?

I have code that I only want to run when my library has loaded.

```
jquery.js -> jqueryui.js.
```

Once jqueryui is loaded I have app specific code I want to execute.  I want to use an event system so I know when this happens.

Is this common practice?

Answer (score 1):

If you load the libraries the "vanilla" way:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jqueryui.js"></script>
```

Then any script tags placed after those will be executed after the preceding scripts have been loaded and parsed.

You can instead get fancier with async loaders such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/), which provide "onload"-like callbacks in which you can execute your own code.